# react native fcm local notification

Tags: android, ios, react-native, push-notification, localnotification

I'm trying to integrate local notifications from [react-native-fcm](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm) into my application. I want notify user once a day, first notification should be pushed in 24 hours after activity was loaded. For now notification appears each minute for IOS, and it's unpredictable for android. Perhaps, it's could be a cache, because, before 'repeat_interval' had been set to 'minute', but - app had been reinstalled.

Please explain what is missed or should be changed to achive the goal?

Would be greate to see some working example of react-native-fcm local notification.

Thanks in advance.

```
componentDidMount() {
this.loadInitialState().done();
FCM.requestPermissions();
FCM.getScheduledLocalNotifications().then(notif => {
  if (notif.length === 0) {
    FCM.scheduleLocalNotification({
        fire_date: new Date().getTime() + (1 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
        id: 'UNIQ_ID_STRING',
        body: 'Do you have rooms available right now?',
        repeat_interval: 'day',
        show_in_foreground: true,
        large_icon: 'ic_launcher',
        icon: 'ic_launcher',
    });
  }
});
```

}